# Notification locale ignored for Twilio in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I am writing tests to validate that a locale is set for a notification and asserting that the correct translation is used in the notification's content. I have been unable to get the locale set on notifications when using Twilio: https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/twilio

I have a notification test for a mail channel that uses a `Mailable` which is working as expected:

```php
public function test_mail_notifications_use_localisation()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $user->notify(
        (new WelcomeMailNotificationStub)
            ->locale('fr')
    );

    $this->assertContains('Bonjour Le Monde',
        app('swift.transport')->messages()[0]->getBody()
    );
}

class WelcomeMailStub extends \Illuminate\Mail\Mailable
{
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('welcome-notification');
    }
}

class WelcomeMailNotificationStub extends \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new WelcomeMailStub);
    }
}
```

I would like to write a similar test for SMS notifications sent via Twilio but in my attempts so far the locale appears to be ignored when sending the notification and the default locale is instead used. Here's what I've come up with:

```php
public function test_sms_notifications_use_localisation()
{
    Notification::fake();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $user->notify(
        (new WelcomeSmsNotificationStub)
            ->locale('fr')
    );

    Notification::assertSentTo(
        $user,
        WelcomeSmsNotificationStub::class,
        function ($notification, $channels) use ($user)
        {
           return $notification->toTwilio($user)->content === 'Bonjour Le Monde'; // test fails here
        }
    );
}

class WelcomeSmsNotificationStub extends \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TwilioChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTwilio($notifiable)
    {
        return (new TwilioSmsMessage())
            ->content(__('welcome_notification.opening_text'));
    }
}
```

If I `dd()` inside the callback in `assertSentTo` like this:

```php
Notification::assertSentTo(
    $user,
    WelcomeSmsNotificationStub::class,
    function ($notification, $channels) use ($user)
    {
       dd(
           $notification,
           $notification->toTwilio($user)
       );

       return $notification->toTwilio($user)->content === 'Bonjour Le Monde'; // test fails here
    }
);
```

I get the following:

```sh
Tests\Unit\Notifications\WelcomeSmsNotificationStub {#116
  +id: "ae164ce6-fa47-4730-b401-e6cc15b27e16"
  +locale: "fr"
}
NotificationChannels\Twilio\TwilioSmsMessage {#2414
  +alphaNumSender: null
  +applicationSid: null
  +maxPrice: null
  +provideFeedback: null
  +validityPeriod: null
  +content: "Default welcome" <== using the default welcome instead of 'fr'
  +from: null
  +statusCallback: null
  +statusCallbackMethod: null
}
```

Any advice on getting this working would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User [exohjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3698787/exohjosh) has solved the issue. I need to explicitly set the translated string's locale in the SMS Notification's `toTwilio` method like this:

```php
__('welcome_notification.opening_text', [], $this->locale)
```

whereas when using Laravel's Mailable this was done automatically.

**Edit**

Event better solution if you're using views is to use `Illuminate\Support\Traits\Localizable` then you can do this:

```
public function toTwilio($notifiable)
{
    return $this->withLocale($this->locale, function() {
        $content = View::make('welcome-notification')->render();

        return (new TwilioSmsMessage())->content($content);
    });
}
```